# Get data from Firebase using angularfire2 (The doc example)

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to get the **database** from **Firebase**.
I have walked through this [tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md).
After I run `ng serve` nothing happened and I have this error in the console:

> [2018-05-21T12:25:48.364Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.0.3): Could not reach Firestore backend.

**environment.ts**:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCip0O3rjU6AXHUKZg7Z26hpLZThTfStsA",
    authDomain: "clientpanel-c4a89.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://clientpanel-c4a89.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "clientpanel-c4a89",
    storageBucket: "clientpanel-c4a89.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "894070096713"
  }
};
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// FIREBASE / ANGULARFIER2
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

// COMPONENTS
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = db.collection('/client').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<h2>The list</h2>

<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{item.email}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And finally, This is [My Firebase](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MzLd-CKgdxZ-cLkTYKrGy7aipkRpn6Ce/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You should remove all the *environment.ts* content from this post. That information is *not* meant to be public.

Comment: did you change your permission to read and write in firebase ?

Comment: @R.Richards In the case of Firebase, those specific keys are actually totally fine to share (although they're not needed for an MCVE here). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Good to know! Thanks for that.

Comment: @R.Richards this project is just for test.

Comment: Yes I did @ChellappanV

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Not yet. I will try @TimM solution and see what will be happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you are using the firebase Real-time Database, but your code uses the firebase Cloud Firestore.

Change `AngularFirestore` to `AngularFireDatabase`.

Working example with your database: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so002

-OR-

Move your data to the Cloud Firestore